# Laravel e function (htmlentities) is not fully working, scripts can still be executed (only once)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, html-entities, htmlspecialchars

I am trying to use the e function in Laravel which is equivalent to the htmlentities PHP function.

In my Form view and Controller I am trying to save a document that uses the e function which looks like this:

Form view:

```
{{ Form::text('client_name') }}
```

Controller:

```
$client = new Client;
$client->client_name = e(Input::get('client_name'));
$client->save();
```

Say I wrote `<script type="text/javascript">alert('gotcha!');</script>` into the client_name field. I then save it to database but when it redirects after it saves to db, it runs this script once! Also just to make sure that the e function was working correctly I looked into my db and it is as expected:

`"&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;alert(&#039;gotcha!&#039;);&lt;/script&gt;"`

My question is how can I avoid executing that javascript `alert('gotcha')`??

Or am I putting this e function or the htmlentities function in the wrong place?'

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running the e() at the wrong place. Escaping is best saved for output of data - not the input.

Your controller should do this:

```
$client = new Client;
$client->client_name = Input::get('client_name');
$client->save();
```

Your Form view is ok with the following - because Form "escapes" the data automatically

```
{{ Form::text('client_name') }}
```

But after you create the client and do the redirect - I bet somewhere you are doing this

```
{{ $client->client_name }}
```

You should change it to this

```
{{{ $client->client_name }}}
```

Note the third { } - which will automatically escape the data for you

Comment: Also another quick question, should we ever use the e function before we insert it into the database? Or no need?

Comment: Generally no jonprasetyo - is is normally best to just escape the output, not the input