# Special characters on messages of custom Request Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

Hi I'm using Laravel version 5.6 and I can show special characters on my .blade.html but now I'm making an edit view and created a custom Request, I already create the function rules() and messages(). But my custom messages in messages() function is not showing the special characters.

Shows like: 'A unidade deve possuir uma senha entre 3 e 60 dÃ­gitos'

And the message was: 'A unidade deve possuir uma senha entre 3 e 60 dígitos'

The code is in here https://github.com/xatanais/laravel_grandLagoonPark/blob/master/app/Http/Requests/AdminUserRequest.php

Some one knows how to fix it?

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is, particularly as you haven't posted any code to show where the text is coming from. That said, you just need to make sure you're using UTF8 encoding everywhere - database and views.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem right here [Laravel e function (htmlentities) is not fully working, scripts can still be executed (only once)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23718646/laravel-e-function-htmlentities-is-not-fully-working-scripts-can-still-be-exe)

For the ones who have enconding issues with showing data from DB just use {{{ DATA_NAME }}} instead of {{ DATA_NAME }}